# transfer of pictures

Tags: transfer

I have a Nikon D3500 that I am trying to transfer pictures to my computer.  I have tried using usb transfer disk but no good.  I tried camera to computer with no results.  Nikon does not have software for ubuntu.  It is 35mm pictures.  Has anyone had this problem before?

Comment: Doesn't it have a memory card?

Comment: You should have added the additional information to your original question instead of opening a new question.

Comment: When you connect the camera via usb, do you see the camera in the file explorer (left column)?  If not, maybe try a different cable.  Should be just drag and drop once you see the camera, open the DCIM folder.....

Comment: @mpboden The direction of the duplicate questions should be reversed because this  question is more informative than the other question.